# jquery json getting all the parts of an object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json file set up with some objects like so:

```
{
"everfi_commons":{
   "info" : {
               "projTotal" : "everfi_Commons",
       "company" : "Everfi",
       "name" : "Commons",
               "type" : "ipad",
       "description" : "this product, bla bla bla bla bla",
       "folder": "everfi_commons",
               "thumbProjName": "COMMONS",
               "thumbDescription" : "bla bla bla bla bla"
   },
   "images" : {
       "image_1" : "image one url",
       "image_2" : "image two url",
       "image_3" : "image three url",
       "image_4" : "image four url"
   }
},
"project_two":{
   "info" : {
               "projTotal" : "project_two",
       "company" : "Everfi",
       "name" : "Commons",
               "type" : "html5",
       "description" : "this product, bla bla bla bla bla",
       "folder": "project_two",
               "thumbProjName": "COMPANY 2",
               "thumbDescription" : "bla bla bla bla bla"
   },
   "images" : {
       "image_1" : "image one url",
       "image_2" : "image two url",
       "image_3" : "image three url",
       "image_4" : "image four url",
               "image_5" : "image five url"
   }
}
}
```

I know how to access very specific parts of the objects, but what I'm wondering is, if there is a way to get into everfi_commons.images and then get all of the image urls no matter how many are listed and put them into a div?

Thanks for any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. First parse the JSON into an object and then iterate over `everfi_commons.images`:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(...);
for(image in data.everfi_commons.images) {
    alert(data.everfi_commons.images[image]); // or whatever you want
}
```

If the JSON is retrieved through an AJAX call then you won't even need the `$.parseJSON` as jQuery will do that automatically if the server sends the correct `Content-Type` in the response.

Comment: cooooooolll, thank you for that!